# TFS revert the current change

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I changed several files in my project and I haven't checked those files in and I want to get the last version of the project from TFS. Right now all the local files have been changed (that broke the project) and I want get the code from the last check-in/changeset and basically void the current changes (that are not checked in). I changed like 10 files and lot of code. Is there a way to get the project into a different folder and run it? I still need the current changes because I was fixing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about backup your current changes first, retrieve the last changeset and move it to your desired folder, and then you can restore your backup in your working folder and continue working on it.

Comment: The shelveset works. I shelve it and it removes the current changes and unshelve to bring it back. Thanks.